# Moving time-range specific files in Python

Tags: python, datetime, directory, conditional-statements, shutil

I'm new to programming, and am working on an assignment having to do with creating a script using Python to detect files from one folder created or modified in the past 24 hours, and then move those files to a different directory.

I've written a code that prints the files' creation and modification date, within
a function that also sorts out the older files/modified more than 24 hours ago. But I'm struggling with creating a script that actually takes those specific files and transfers them to a new folder. This is the first part of my code:

```
    import os,time
    import datetime
    import shutil


    now = dt.datetime.now()
    ago = now-dt.timedelta(hours=24)
    strftime = "%H:%M %m/%d/%Y"
    created = 'C:\\Users\\Jacquelin\e\Desktop\\created'
    dest = 'C:\\Users\\Jacqueline\\Desktop\\dest'


    for root, dirs,files in os.walk(created):  
        for fname in files:
            path = os.path.join(root, fname)
            st = os.stat(path)    
            mtime = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(st.st_mtime)
            if mtime > ago:
                print "True:  ", fname, " at ", mtime.strftime("%H:%M %m/%d/%Y")
            else:
                print False

    for fname in os.listdir(created):
        if mtime > ago:                   
            shutil.move(path, dest)
            print "moved to dest", fname
```

I'm using shutil.move to transfer the files, and have tried a million things-- but can't figure it out! I'm also working on turning these into functions to simplify things. So far, this is what I have:

```
    def find_info():                                 #this first func. works fine.
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(created):
        for fname in files:
            path = os.path.join(root, fname)                                        
            st = os.stat(path)    
            mtime = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(st.st_mtime)                          
        if mtime > ago:
            print True
        else:
            print False
```

For the "move" function, I feel like this is the right idea but, not knowing the variables to pass, I've left the parentheses empty. And *that* returns a crazy long list of booleans. So.

```
    def move():
        for fname in os.listdir(created):
            path = os.path.join(root, fname)
            if find_info(fname) == True:                   
                shutil.move(path, dest)
                print "moved to dest", fname

    print find_info()                           #variable? is one even needed?
    print move()                                #variable???? 

    print os.listdir(dest)
    print os.listdir(created)
```

I'm not sure what variable(s) to pass into the functions. Afterwards, I'm printing the directories to see if the files have indeed been transferred. The damned things won't move.

Thanks!!

Comment: Could you explain, how you are using `shutil.move` and what goes wrong with it? Error messages, etc.? Also, note that path with backslashes may be interpreted wrong as backslash has special meaning (like in `\n`), so you have to escape it `"c:\\Users\\…"` or (better) use `os.path.join`.

Comment: I've just changed my code, and I'll put it above with the original message; With shutil.move, it's just not moving the files! I'm having the program print the origin and destination directories, but no transfer has taken place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost here. Just invoke `shutil.move` function after you detected that particular file is eligible for moveing (i.e. before/after/instead of `print("True:  ", fname, " at ", mtime.strftime("%H:%M %m/%d/%Y"))`). Something like this will work:

```
import os,time
import datetime
import shutil

import datetime as dt

now = dt.datetime.now()
ago = now-dt.timedelta(hours=24)
strftime = "%H:%M %m/%d/%Y"
created = 'here'
dest = 'there'

for root, dirs,files in os.walk(created):  
    for fname in files:
        path = os.path.join(root, fname)
        st = os.stat(path)    
        mtime = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(st.st_mtime)
        if mtime > ago:
            print("True:  ", fname, " at ", mtime.strftime("%H:%M %m/%d/%Y"))
            shutil.move(path, dest)
            # this is actual move
```

The following snippet is all wrong and not necessary:

```
for fname in os.listdir(created):
    if mtime > ago:                   
        shutil.move(path, dest)
        print "moved to dest", fname
```

Here `mtime`, `path` and `dest` don't depend on loop variable `fname`, so it is not clear why we need loop here and what is intended behaviour of this fragment.

Note that that your function `find_info()` (which we actually don't need either) returns nothing: this function *prints* `True` or `False` instead of *returning* it.

Comment: Oh my goodness this is magical. Thank you so much! So I don't actually need to create any functions? I can just use for loops, and call it a day?

Comment: You need functions if you have some isolated part of your logic that solves particular sub-problem of your problem and potentially can be used several times in different parts of the program. There's no need to create functions just to create functions.